# Display Blank Columns When Column Names Are Not Provided

Tags: sql

I was searching for this question but was not to find this answer but after a struggle, I found it. So I am posting it here just to help others, nothing else.

Suppose this was the structure of table:

| Table Name | Field Name | Default Values | COMMENTS | HEADERS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EMPLOYEE | ID |  | Unique Id | UNIQUE_ID |
| EMPLOYEE | NAME |  | Employee Name | EMPLOYEE_NAME |
| EMPLOYEE |  | "No Badge Found" | Badge Id | BADGE |
| EMPLOYEE |  |  | Status | STATUS |

And this was the expected output:
UNIQUE_ID | EMPLOYEE_NAME | BADGE | STATUS
-|-|-|-
10001 | Ram Sharma | No Badge Found |
10002 | Mohan Sharma | No Badge Found |
10003 | Yogesh Pant | No Badge Found |
10004 | Vikas Mehta | No Badge Found |
10005 | Mukesh Bisht | No Badge Found |
10006 | Raman Singh | No Badge Found |

Comment: Tag the question with the dbms you're using

Answer (score 0):

So here is the query.

```
DECLARE @EMPTY_VARIABLE VARCHAR(1)
DECLARE @BADGE_VARIABLE VARCHAR(20)
SET @EMPTY_VARIABLE = ""
SET @BADGE_VARIABLE ="No Badge Found"

SELECT 
ID                AS   "UNIQUE_ID",
NAME              AS   "EMPLOYEE_NAME",
@BADGE_VARIABLE   AS   "BADGE",
@EMPTY_VARIABLE   AS   "STATUS"
FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

[And Yes you will get output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDZAZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
ID               AS  'UNIQUE_ID',
NAME             AS   'EMPLOYEE_NAME'
'No Badge Found' AS 'BADGE'
''               AS  'STATUS'
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

Here I have found another answer and I am posting it as well.